# Unique tangent to conics

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given a conic section $C$ it is easy to prove analytically (or algebraically) that there is a unique tangent to $C$ in each point. Is there a simple synthetic proof of this fact? References are also welcome.

Comment: What is the synthetic definition of "tangent line at a point"?

Comment: What is a synthetic proof

Comment: By synthetic you mean that which includes all conics? If so slope of tangent is found by direct  diierentiation.

Comment: A synthetic proof is  a classical geometric proof a la Euclid.

Comment: And the classical definition of a tangent to a conic is a line that intersects the conic in a single point such that the conic is on one side of the line (with a slight modification in the case of hyperbolas).

Comment: Consider 2 planes: one tangent to a cone in the point of interest, another is the secant plane. The intersection is a line. Prove it is tangent to conic. Very straightforward.

Comment: You have constructed a unique tangent. I do not see how this is supposed to show  that there cannot be two of them.

Comment: Prove that a tangent must belong to both planes. That makes it unique.